# SoundCloud HTML5 widget no autoplay, iOS

Tags: ios, html, soundcloud

The HTML5 SoundCloud widgets autoplay feature is not working on iOS5 and iOS6.

I have not tested lower than iOS 5.

See: http://www.bushytunes.net/test.asp

This page has the feature enabled by including the `auto_play=true` parameter in the iframe src.

Can this be fixed? Or is there a hack I can add to my application to enable this feature?

Comment: Are you designing a webpage that will include this widget, or are you writing a native iOS app that will include a UIWebView that will contain the widget?

Comment: It will be a webpage using the html5 widget in the iOS Safari browser.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Autoplay is disabled for any audio or video on all iOS devices, this is Apple's decision. Here's a link to the documentation that is saying that playback has to be controlled by the user: 
http://developer.apple.com/library/safari/#documentation/AudioVideo/Conceptual/Using_HTML5_Audio_Video/Device-SpecificConsiderations/Device-SpecificConsiderations.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009523-CH5-SW1

Playback has to be initiated by user action. As far as I know there is no hack that would let you enable it.