# Soundcloud HTML5 widget not playing on mobile

Tags: soundcloud

Starting today, we're noticing an issue where our HTML 5 SoundCloud widget does not play via most iPhone and Android (Nexus 4, 7, etc) mobile phones.

I've created a basic example using boilerplate SC embed code from the website:

http://musiclibre.org/soundcloud.html

Works fine on my laptop but when you visit this URL with an iPhone / Nexus 4, etc... it does not playback any sound.  When I debug the mobile clients I see the following URL is hanging:

Request URL:https://ec-media.soundcloud.com/R1YjVVV5DVha.128.mp3?ff61182e3c2ecefa438cd02102d0e385713f0c1faf3b033959566bfc0e04ed13fd2d850af8801408aa334ddd90a80d55d56996eb9f937b59e7656fb786847061c39dee4d95&AWSAccessKeyId=AKIAJ4IAZE5EOI7PA7VQ&Expires=1386116798&Signature=Qtbr0JGl2YWUtiDcyptFpd5JNko%3D

No JS errors.  widget.play() does get called.  But since the mp3 stream is hanging, no music plays and the player freezes up.

Any ideas?

Comment: is it only `autoplay` that doesn't work?

Comment: please see http://stackoverflow.com/a/14905052/236135

Comment: possible duplicate of [SoundCloud HTML5 widget no autoplay, iOS](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14900840/soundcloud-html5-widget-no-autoplay-ios)

Comment: @gryzzly not quite a duplicate.  Here we're trying to call `widget.play()` from a click event, although people experiencing that bug may come here too.

Answer (score 1):

@gryzzly autoplay stopped working awhile ago, but by explicitly calling widget.play() it was working as recently as a week or so ago.  Now doing that locks up the player. If I check for mobile and do not call widget.play(), the user can click on the widget and play the track.  Alas... the workaround appears to now be broken.  Thanks for the insight.

Comment: Hey @William, I came across this issue recently. I have a button and SC widget. When after page load I play audio from the widget, then my button control works. But when I first tap my button, the widget stops working. Of course all this happen on mobile browsers. On Desktop everything is fine. Is there any solution you have found?